# When plotting graphs using networkx, how can I use colors on edges?

Tags: python, networkx

when plotting with networkx, how would I approach using color values to a set of edges?

For example this plots 3 nodes,

```
edges = pd.DataFrame({'node_1': [1, 2, 3],
                      'node_2': [2, 3, 1],
                      'edge_id': [5, 4, 6]})

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges, 'node_1', 'node_2', True, nx.Graph())
nx.draw(G, node_size = 100)
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

How would I be able to use data like this to color in the edges?

```
draw = pd.DataFrame({'edge_id': [5, 4, 6],
                    'edge_colour': ['AE6017', 'F15B2E', 'F15B2E']})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw the edges and the nodes in separate steps. And there you can provide a list of colors to either one of them. In order to draw them separately, first their positions need to be calculated. For most graphs, the best layout is obtained calling [`spring_layout`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout.html).

Demo code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

edges = pd.DataFrame({'node_1': [1, 2, 3],
                      'node_2': [2, 3, 1],
                      'edge_id': [5, 4, 6]})
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges, 'node_1', 'node_2', True, nx.Graph())

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size = 100, node_color='deepskyblue')
cmap_colors = plt.cm.Set1.colors
edge_colors = [cmap_colors[edge_ind %  len(cmap_colors)] for edge_ind in range(len(G.edges))]
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, width=1.0, edge_color=edge_colors)

plt.show()
```

[image: result]

Alternatively, you can substitute `nx.draw` by [`nx.draw_networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx). `nx.draw_networkx` is similar to `nx.draw`, but allows many more options. If desired, you can give the positions, if not they get calculated automatically. It accepts the same `edge_color=...` as `nx.draw_networkx_edges`.